# Solving for variables inside cos() and sin()

Tags: c++, c, math

```
double g[2][2];

g[0][0] = cos(M_PI*0.5*(c - w*0.5));
g[0][1] = sin(M_PI*0.5*(c - w*0.5));

g[1][0] = cos(M_PI*0.5*(c + w*0.5));
g[1][1] = sin(M_PI*0.5*(c + w*0.5));
```

The matrix g is given. How do I rewrite the above to find the value of (c,w)?

Comment: Writing your maths equations in C and/or C++ doesn't make this a programming question!

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/ might be a better place for this type of questions.

Comment: -1 math question disguised as programming.

Answer (score 1):

Use `atan2` to determine pi/2*(c-w/2) and pi/2*(c+w/2) -- of course there's an ambiguity of integer*2pi in both and there's nothing you can do about that. So you know have a,b such that c-w/2 = a + 4*m and c+w/2 = b + 4*n where m,n are unknown integers.

Now c = (a+b)/2 + 2*(m+n) and w = (b-a) + 4*(n-m) where, again, m,n are arbitrary unknown integers.

You might prefer to write, let's say, k=m+n; then c = (a+b)/2 + 2k and w = (b-a) + 4k - 4m where now k,m are arbitrary unknown integers.

Answer (score 0):

you got something like

```
g1 = cos(a - b)
g2 = sin(a - b)
g3 = cos(a + b)
g4 = sin(a + b)
```

so

```
atan2(g1,g2) = A = a - b [+ N*2*PI]
atan2(g3,g4) = B = a + b [+ N*2*PI]
```

and

```
a = (A + B) / 2
b = B - a
```

It is more a math question than a programming question though.

Comment: Using only the cosines will give you some spurious solutions that would have been ruled out by considering the signs of the sines. Better to use `atan2` in situations like this.

Comment: That's right. I agree. This solution is not good.